# How to replace a row value in a pandas dataframe after a desired number is achieved?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a simple piece of code, something similar to what I am doing. I'm trying to replace the value after 1 with a -1. But in my case, how would I do it if I don't know where the 1's are in a dataframe of over 1000's of rows?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Craig', 'Davis', 'Anthony', 'Tony'], 'Age':[22, 27, 24, 33], 'Employed':[0, 1, 0, 0]})

df
```

I have this...

| Name | Age | Employed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Craig | 22 | 0 |
| Davis | 27 | 1 |
| Anthony | 24 | 0 |
| Tony | 33 | 0 |

I want something similar to this but iterable through 1000's of rows

| Name | Age | Employed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Craig | 22 | 0 |
| Davis | 27 | 1 |
| Anthony | 24 | -1 |
| Tony | 33 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

Use `shift` to get the next row after a 1:

```
df = df.loc[df['Employed'].shift() == 1, 'Employed'] = -1
print(df)

# Output
      Name  Age  Employed
0    Craig   22         0
1    Davis   27         1
2  Anthony   24        -1
3     Tony   33         0
```